# what's the best way to wait on bamboo until any task (script, job) on external server is finished ?

Tags: build, bamboo

Is there the best way to wait on bamboo build or deploy until any task (script, job) on external server is finished ? 
External server doesn't send any event but accessible via ssh or http api.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this external server running a Bamboo agent?

Comment: yes, you need remote agents if you're having a big list of builds/deploys on bamboo

Comment: If the external server is running an agent you should have full control via the Script Task module in ensuring that it finishes before moving to the next. Tasks are sequential, Job are parallel.

Comment: yes, I implemented it by this way already, 
but it looks a little bit tricky

Comment: OK, then you need to provide more information: what's so tricky about it? I (and I assume many) use it all the time. Unless the task is itself doing background tasks asynchronously - which your script would then have to wait for, I'm not clear what the problem is. Can you give a clear example? Also, if you want to essentially "let this server do its thing while other tasks happen, but overall wait until everything is done" then maybe put that one task into a job by itself.

Comment: well, if I run Script Task it makes at least one worker busy cause it has to wait (send requests in the loop). From my point of view it will be better to create plugin-trigger that will send requests every _n_ seconds and check status of task on remote server. In this case next stage will start once it's triggered

Comment: Wait, but that worker is marked as busy because it **is** busy! Why would you want to add to the load? BTW, you can run multiple agents on a machine, if that's what you really want. With that you can keep adding to a "workers" load if you really wish.

Answer (score -1):

Add script task with wget or curl execution in loop until remote service response is expected.

Comment: right, but as you said other service can't start interaction then you need Bamboo to do it. You can use Bamboo agent to do it or create plugin which will check for remote service status and then trigger plan when you need it

Comment: y, I was thinking about plugin but had to check if there's something that easier than new plugin